# how to copy files from windows to linux witout password using a script or program?

Tags: linux, windows, file-copy

I did this to copy files between Windows and Linux.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\668340\My Documents\putty>pscp  "C:\Documents and Settings\563456\abc.txt" "auto_root@10.39.5.41:/home/auto/"
```

But it prompts for a password and how do i automate this task using *private/public key pairs* between windows and linux

Even `winscp` works but only problem is that i have to use hard coded password in the code, which I don't want. Instead I want to use private/public key addition concept but not aware how to do it when it is windows.

**EDIT**:i mean i can go with passwordless authentication but still it involes ,the manual process of generating public,private keys(.ppk) using `puttygen.exe` in windows and then
copying the public key to `.ssh\authorized` in linux.is there any way to automate this.

**EDIT**:if there is any of copying files by running some shell script of command in unix to copy file to windows that could also be usefull as i can create public/private keys in unix automatiaclly.

Comment: You can use the same public/private key pair on all your windows machines. Copying files from unix to windows is difficult (only way is using SMB/CIFS), but you e.g. run a web server on your unix machine and then let the windows client download files using e.g. [wget compiled for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to authenticate without prior key exchange, I see no other option than using password authentication (at least the first time).

So you need to hard-code the password in your script.  You can give the password to `pscp` with its `-pw` option. But, I do not know how safe this is (at least in Linux, all user normally can see the command line of all processes).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to type passwords or generate keys, I suggest the following:

1. disable networking on both machines (security first!).
2. enable password-less login on both machines.
3. insert a floppy disk into machine A and copy the files onto the floppy.
4. remove the floppy from machine A and walk to machine B.
5. insert the floppy into machine B and copy the files onto machine B.

If you happen to have a Win 95 machine then you'll be excited to know that this is the networking model for which it was designed.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT following the update of the question:

The easiest way to copy files over network is probably SMB/CIFS - on Linux side you'd use [SAMBA](http://www.samba.org/) to either provide network share for Windows or to mount sharres exported by the Windows machine.

If you want to use ssh a look at [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), which includes command line `scp`, that should be able to use key authentication. But then again: is it acceptable in your situation to use keys not protected with a password?